# Why i cant get element into useRef?

Tags: reactjs, types

I'm trying to get input in component Home

```js
const Home = () => {
  let inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const deleteInputText = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    dispatch(changeInputSearh(""));
    if (inputRef && inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="input-home">
      <MyInput
        type="text"
        placeholder="поиск..."
        value={inputOption}
        onChange={changeInputRedux}
        className="input-home__inp"
        ref={inputRef}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

In component MyInput I wrote `forwardRef`

```js
const MyInput = React.forwardRef((props: any, ref) => {
  console.log(ref);
  return <input {...props}></input>;
});
```

In console I see null but not input. Why do I not see the element

```js
{current: null}
current: null
[[Prototype]]:Object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not adding the `ref` to the input, you're only passing it down to your custom `MyInput` component.

```js
const MyInput = React.forwardRef((props: any, ref) => {
  console.log(ref);
  return <input {...props} ref={ref}></input>;
});
```